# Tedious Package when outputparameter value exceed limit characters（8000）

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, tedious

I am using Store procedure output parameter below, when the value over 8000 characters the value will got cut off.   Anyone could give me some ideas or direction how to fix this? I saw someone said using several variable set up in store procedure to take the value. But the problem is I don't know how much 8000 characters we will receive and it will much more than 8000.

```
request.addOutputParameter('JSONOUTPUT1', TYPES.VarChar);
    request.addOutputParameter('JSONOUTPUT2', TYPES.VarChar);

    request.on('returnValue', (name, value, matadata)=>{
      result[name] = value; // if value is over 8000 characters will got truncated.
    });
```

For the normal query sql result, I am using below code to receive data returned from sql server:

```
request.on("row", columns => {
        result += columns[0].value; 
      });
```

the above way we are reading the data from db chunk by chunk it works perfect！ but it seems for store procedure output I did not find such a way in tedious.

I am appreciate in advance if anyone faced similar issue and could provide a solution.

Comment: In SQL, the max length of the varchar type is 8000. Is it possible to change the data type to 'text' or 'longtext' instead of varchar? Those data types should be able to hold enough data without being truncated.

Comment: i run the storeprocedure in sql and display the JSONOUTPUT2 i could get the entire value, but in Node JS level i got truncated value for JSONOUTPUT2. No matter what variable type (varchar, nvarchar, text)i set up in SQL server is ok, but in tedious outputparameter if i set Text or NTextit will throw error. So i feel I should try to resolve the issue in Tedious Node JS side, instead of Sql Server side. .

Comment: This is the error when i am using Text in tedious:
Error received from database side Invalid parameter 2 ('@JSONOUTPUT1'):  Data type 0x23 is a deprecated large object, or LOB, but is marked as output parameter.  Deprecated types are not supported as output parameters.  Use current large object types instead.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who face the same error below is how i handled in the end:
Instead of using outputstoreprocedue parameter, using query as well. Read data still row by row, chunk by chunk.

```
request.on("row", columns => {    
columns.forEach((column)=> {
result[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
  })     
});
 request.on('requestCompleted', () => {
    connection.close();
    done(error, result);
  });
connection.execSql(request);
```

Below is the query:

```
const query = `DECLARE @json1 AS VarChar(MAX)
DECLARE @json2 AS VarChar(MAX)
EXEC dbo.[abc_storeprocedure]
@i_STORE_NBR = '${input1}', 
@jsonOutput1 = @json1 OUTPUT,
@jsonOutput2 = @json2 OUTPUT
SELECT @json1 as 'emailList'
SELECT @json2 as 'candidateList' `
```

FYI: in tedious 6.6.5 Text is deprecated